# Connect to remote mysql server from my application. Problem is that Mysql server is on LAN

Tags: mysql, networking, ssh, ip-address

I have one remote server that runs apache+mysql and i have developed an appication in my home computer to administrate my database. My application from my home-pc connects to my remote server and i am administrating my database (as i said mysql runs on the same remote machine) from my home pc.

The following days, due to heavy traffic i am going to use a second remote server as a database server. My first remote server will handle apache only, and the new remote server will handle the mysql-database only.

The new mysql remote server will be connected with the old server in a LAN. So my website in the apache server can communicate with the database like "192.168.x.x" (you got the point).

Problem is: How my home application will communicate with the database server???? Database server will be in LAN together with my web server, and only web server can "see" the database server like "192.168.x.x". How can my home application can "see" the database server which is "hidden" in the LAN??

I am an experienced programmer but have little experience with networks, excuse any possible non-sense i wrote in the description, i hope you got my point and i would be glad if you can give me some help or point me to any usefull articles-how-to's.

Thank you guys!

Comment: This might be a better question for serverfault.com

Comment: can an admin move this to serverfault or i should re-post this?

Comment: u need a public ip for your database server like your old server does. Or u can `ssh` into your old server, from there `ssh 192.168.x.x` which is your database server private ip

Answer (score 0):

an application I use utilizes an ssh tunnel to accomplish this.  sorry that's nowhere's near a complete answer, but perhaps it will start you in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

How is the network configured?

```
[home pc] -> {internet} -> [firewall] -> [webserver] -> [database]
```

or

```
[home pc] -> {internet} -> [firewall] ->  [webserver]
                                      |       |
                                      `-> [database]
```

In either, if the database server is the only machine that will be running MySQL, you should be able to configure the firewall and/or webserver to forward the MySQL port (3306 by default) so that as far as the outside world is concerned, the DB server is directly accesible, even though you're actually routing packets through the firewall/webserver.

Comment: the configuration will be [home pc]-> {internet} -> [webserver+firewall] -LAN-> [database server]

the web server will communicate using a second NIC with the database server. 

So, if i understand correctly, i will have to setup my server for port-forwarding. 

My application right now connects to my one and only web-database-server using the ip and the standard port. If i understand correctly my application's connection details will not have to change after i setup the databaser server.

Comment: The only change that must be done when the new database server will be ready, is to setup port forwardind from my web server to the database server (which only he can see through the LAN).

Is that correct or i missed something?? Please confirm because i dont have a lot of hardware experience and i feel kinda lost!

And of course thank you very very much for your help!!! I really needed it! :)

Comment: Yeah, configure the webserver to port forward 3306 to the database server. ONce that's done, your home PC will connect to the same IP/port, but the packets will be transparently forwarded to the database server, instead of staying on the web server.

Comment: Thank you for your help Marc, you pointed me to the right direction, i will research for more details and i ll do the neccesary configuration... i ll post another question only if it is absolutely necesary lets hope i will make it work :) thank you again!